# How to capture the error caused by file not found in this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this code to find the name of an excel file inside the application directory. But if the file is not found i want to give an error message. How can i do that using c#? Below is the code i used to search the file.

```
string linksfile;
string [] excelfile = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\", "*.xlsx");
linksfile = excelfile[0];

MessageBox.Show(linksfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    string linksfile;
    string [] excelfile = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\", "*.xlsx");

    if(excelfile.Length > 0)
    {
        linksfile = excelfile[0];

        MessageBox.Show(linksfile);
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("File not found");
    }
```

Comment: `GetFiles()` will never return null.

Comment: If file not found an exception throws named "OndexOutOfRangeException" at linksfile = excelfile[0]; how can i get over it?

Comment: i did it like this,  string linksfile;
string [] excelfile = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\", "*.xlsx");
but still it gives me the exception 



if (excelfile.Length < 0)
{

MessageBox.Show("Survey Links file not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
KillProcesses.KillExcelProcess();
KillProcesses.KillWordProcess();
Application.Exit();

}
else
{
MessageBox.Show(linksfile);
linksfile = excelfile[0];
return false;
}

Comment: MessageBox.Show(linksfile); 
linksfile = excelfile[0]; 
return false;

You're first accessing it, then assigning it. 

linksfile = excelfile[0]; 
MessageBox.Show(linksfile); 
return false;

Comment: I did that too..but still i get the exception at linksfile=excelfile[0];

Comment: Change if (excelfile.Length < 0) to if (excelfile.Length < 1) or if (excelfile.Length <= 0)

Comment: string [] excelfile = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\", "*.xlsx"); 
if (excelfile.Length < 1)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Survey Links file not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop); 
 KillProcesses.KillExcelProcess(); 
 KillProcesses.KillWordProcess(); 
 Application.Exit(); 
} 
else 
{ 
 MessageBox.Show(excelfile[0]);
 return false; 
}

Comment: Got it sorted by giving the exact file name SeToY. Thanks a million!

Comment: YOUR CODE WAS RIGHT!!!!! it's something wrong with my project files. It's okay now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should check `if (excelFile.Length > 0)`.

Comment: However I will add a try/catch for permissions problems.

Comment: If file not found an exception throws named "OndexOutOfRangeException" how can i get over it?